# Convert access token to cookie or support access token based authentication

Tags: next.js, access-token, auth0

I have React + Next JS + auth0 web app that uses session/cookie-based authentication to protect pages and APIs. I want to invoke one of the APIs programmatically from elsewhere and the only credential I have to make an API call is getting an access token.
I'm looking for one of the 2 potential solutions:

1. How to generate cookies using an access token on the client side to call web app?
2. How can the nextjs+react+auth0 web app accept an access token as a credential?

Since I manage both sides of the code, I'm open to any solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide an alternate authentication in your API call. For example with NextAuth on an API route

e.g.

```js
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import { authOptions } from '../../auth/[...nextauth]';

export default async function handler(
    req, //: NextApiRequest,
    res  //: NextApiResponse
) {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
    
    let user = null;
    if (session) user = session.user;
    else {
        const token = req.headers.get('Authorization').replace(/^Bearer /, '');
        user = await validateToken(token);
        if(!user){ //validate token and generate the user defined by your external caller
            res.status(401).end();
            return;
        }
    }
    // do work with authenticated user;
    // since your comment about needing a cookie for an upstream server:
    fetch('upsteamurl', {
        headers:{
            'Set-Cookie': makeCookieHeader(req.query.monitor, 'sent', {path:'/', secure:false, sameSite:'strict', httpOnly:false}))
        }
    }).then(... // use the upstream response
    ...
    }
    
function makeCookieHeader(name, value, opts){
    let header = name +'='+value;
    if(opts){

        if (opts.maxAge) opts.expires = new Date(Date.now() + opts.maxAge);

        if (opts.path     ) header += '; path=' + opts.path;
        if (opts.expires  ) header += '; expires=' + opts.expires.toUTCString();
        if (opts.domain   ) header += '; domain=' + opts.domain;
        if (opts.sameSite ) header += '; samesite=' + (opts.sameSite === true ? 'strict' : opts.sameSite.toLowerCase());
        if (opts.secure   ) header += '; secure';
        if (opts.httpOnly ) header += '; httponly';
    }

    return header;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But that will not set up cookies and session which I need further down the line in the chain of further API calls I make within the server. Since other calls inside the server API passes cookies to other server APIs that need cookie info.

Comment: Cookies are a client-browser solution. You wrote ' I want to invoke one of the APIs programmatically from elsewhere'. If this is not from another browser then you should not rely on cookies. If you really need to pass a cookie from the API to another service then you should be able to generate a valid cookie header. I've updated my answer